# How to align checkbox and select?

Tags: javascript, html, css

my current code is the following. When I display the following, after sunday, monday etc..  is not been able to align correctly. How can I able to align checkbox, day, two select in a nice manner. Please help me to achieve the same

```css
.select-style {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fafafa url("img/icon-select.png") no-repeat 90% 50%;
}

.select-style select {
  padding: 5px 8px;
  width: 130%;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.select-style select:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Working Hours :</label>
  <div class="checkboxFour">
    <input type="checkbox" id="sun" style="width: 10%!important;">
    <label for="sun">Sunday</label>
    <select class="select-style">From
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select-style">To
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sun" style="width: 10%!important;">
    <label for="sun">Monday</label>
    <select class="select-style">From
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select-style">To
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sun" style="width: 10%!important;">
    <label for="sun">Tuesday</label>
    <select class="select-style">From
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select-style">To
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sun" style="width: 10%!important;">
    <label for="sun">Wednesday</label>
    <select class="select-style">From
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select-style">To
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
    </select>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my current code. But I am not able to align the same. Is there any way to align the same. I am new to html and designing. Please help me to align the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could use table instead like :

```css
.select-style {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fafafa url("img/icon-select.png") no-repeat 90% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Working Hours :</label>
  <table class="checkboxFour">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="sun" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="sun">Sunday</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="select-style">From
          <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
          <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
          <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
          <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="select-style">To
          <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
          <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
          <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
          <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="sun" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="sun">Monday</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="select-style">From
          <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
          <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
          <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
          <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="select-style">To
          <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
          <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
          <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
          <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="sun" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="sun">Tuesday</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="select-style">From
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
    </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="select-style">To
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
    </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="sun" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="sun">Wednesday</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="select-style">From
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
    </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="select-style">To
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
    </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**What options do you have?**

Well there are plenty like flexbox, tables, grids, etc. I prefer grid for this scenario.

**What changes you need to make?**

- Set `display:grid` to your **checkboxFour** container.
- Set `template columns` which is *1fr 3fr 3fr 3fr* (you can *tweak them around*, **fr represents fractions** of the **total width** which we have set to 500px, or you can give a fixed size for each columns *instead of fr in px,%,etc*).
- Remove the break tags `<br>`

**How does CSS Grid works?**

Well, since we have used *grid-template-columns* which has (1fr 3fr 3fr 3fr) that represents, the first column element will take the 1fr column, 2nd 3fr, 3rd 3fr, 4th 3fr and then the 5th will again take 1fr and it repeats again. In the given code,

```
1st column = checkbox
2nd column = label
3rd column = select
4th column = select 
(Since we removed the `<br>` or it would be the 5th column element)
5th column = checkbox and so on..
```

```css
.checkboxFour{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:1fr 3fr 3fr 3fr;
width:500px;
}
.select-style {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fafafa url("img/icon-select.png") no-repeat 90% 50%;
}

.select-style select {
  padding: 5px 8px;
  width: 130%;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.select-style select:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Working Hours :</label>
  <div class="checkboxFour">
    <input type="checkbox" id="sun" style="width: 10%!important;">
    <label for="sun">Sunday</label>
    <select class="select-style">From
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select-style">To
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sun" style="width: 10%!important;">
    <label for="sun">Monday</label>
    <select class="select-style">From
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select-style">To
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sun" style="width: 10%!important;">
    <label for="sun">Tuesday</label>
    <select class="select-style">From
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select-style">To
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sun" style="width: 10%!important;">
    <label for="sun">Wednesday</label>
    <select class="select-style">From
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select-style">To
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> First wrap `label` & `input` & `select` in `row` class,like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <input type="checkbox" id="sun" style="width: 10%!important;">
  <label for="sun">Sunday</label>
  <select class="select-style">From
    <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
    <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
    <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
    <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
  </select>
  <select class="select-style">To
    <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
    <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
    <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
    <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

> Now you can use `display:table-*` like this:

```
.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.row select, .row input, .row label {
  display: table-cell;
  margin:0 5px 5px 0;
}
```

```css
.select-style {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fafafa url("img/icon-select.png") no-repeat 90% 50%;
}

.select-style select {
  width: 130%;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.select-style select:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

table {
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.row select, .row input, .row label{
  display: table-cell;
  margin:0 5px 5px 0;
}

.form-group > label {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Working Hours :</label>
    <div class="checkboxFour">
    <div class="row">
      <input type="checkbox" id="sun" style="width: 10%!important;">
      <label for="sun">Sunday</label>
      <select class="select-style">From
        <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
        <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
        <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
        <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
      </select>
      <select class="select-style">To
        <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
        <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
        <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
        <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="checkbox" id="sun" style="width: 10%!important;">
      <label for="sun">Monday</label>
      <select class="select-style">From
        <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
        <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
        <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
        <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
      </select>
      <select class="select-style">To
        <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
        <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
        <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
        <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="checkbox" id="sun" style="width: 10%!important;">
      <label for="sun">Tuesday</label>
      <select class="select-style">From
        <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
        <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
        <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
        <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
      </select>
      <select class="select-style">To
        <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
        <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
        <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
        <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="checkbox" id="sun" style="width: 10%!important;">
      <label for="sun">Wednesday</label>
      <select class="select-style">From
        <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
        <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
        <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
        <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
      </select>
      <select class="select-style">To
        <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
        <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
        <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
        <option value="24:00">24.00</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```